# Chain SelectMany instead of using a JOIN statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Let say I have:

[image]

I have to find all the classes that belong to a specific school (IdSchool=2) and that are from science for example.

Anyways because I find LINQ very eassy to use I do:

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var classesOfInterest = context.Schools
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Teachers)
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Classes)
                        .Where(x => /* custom criteria */ )
                        .ToList();
}
```

**So my question is:** Is using this approach instad of using a join statement bad practice? Should I use a JOIN statement instead? There are cases where I chain 5 "SelectMany" statements. Right now it works great because database is small. If I where to be working with a big database is this something I should try to avoid?

Comment: I would expect the translated SQL query execution to be much slower with the `SelectMany` approach.  I would definitely use joins.  But don't take my word for it.  Log the generated SQL, compare the execution plans, and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks @sstan. Results are very similar. I guess I will need to try this agains a large database and compare the results like you say. It will be nice if I could chain it using SelectMany. Its so faster to build the queries like this.

Comment: Actually this is the preferred EF approach. EF uses the meta information of the "navigation" properties to generate the joins for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using this approach instad of using a join statement bad practice?

Not at all. In fact this is the **recommended** (or **preferred**) practice when working with EF. The so called **navigation properties** are one of the beauty of the EF. When you have them (and you do), you'd never need to use "manual" joins. You just "navigate" if they are objects/collections and EF generates the joins for you if like you wrote them, but without the need to remember which field from the one table joins to which field of the other.

For instance, let take this simplified version of your query:

```
var queryA = context.Schools.SelectMany(x => x.Teachers);
var sqlA = queryA.ToString();
```

and the equivalent using joins:

```
var queryB = from s in context.Schools
             join t in context.Teachers on s.Id equals t.IdSchoool
             select t;
var sqlB = queryB.ToString();
```

you will see that `sqlA` and `sqlB` are one and the same.

Comment: are you sure `SelectMany` of `IQueryable<T>` is translated to an inner join?

Comment: @octavioccl Absolutely. What else? `SelectMany` is for instance when you write `from s in db.Schools from t in s.Teachers select t`. And it's translated to `INNER JOIN`. If you use `s.Teachers.DefaultIfEmpty()`, then you get `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Well, I was thinking it could also be a cross join with a where condition. As far I know a double `from` in Linq is translated to a `SelectMany` call, that's why I thought it could be translated to a cross join.